# include(ZipArchive.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: yii

when i need to extract file gives this error

include(ZipArchive.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

```
          mkdir("project/".$tp_name, 0700);

            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open('yii.zip') === TRUE)
            {
                $zip->extractTo('project/'.$tp_name);
                $zip->close();
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make sure the Zip extensions are enabled. Check your php.ini file for the following:

On Windows: `extension=php_zip.dll`

On MAC and Linux: `extension=zip.so`

Comment: Thanks  for reply..ragingprodigy

Comment: @user3312547 Yii has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not this extension is enabled. You need to adjust the php.ini file on your "online" server. Talk to your webhost, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe install php-zip first, then tinker with the php.ini file afterwards. For instance, on Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install php-zip